# Is it best practice to issue “FROM Table AS a WITH (NOLOCK) “ when doing multiple COUNT(*) and UNION ALL results? Does it even matter?

Tags: sql-server

The top part of the query looks for all columns in all tables in a database that have -1 value in a column suffixed with ‘SID’ and stores results in a global temp table.  The query was being blocked by some other process and was spotted by one of our hotshot DBAs who said, “this query is too big, it’s massive and it’s blocking other processes”  the @sql variable builds a dynamic query like this and unions results except there are several hundred queries that are unioned.

```
SELECT 'R_SStaff' as TheSchema, 'AlertF8992' as TheTable, 'RecipientStaffSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount FROM [R_SStaff].[AlertF8992] WHERE [RecipientStaffSID] = -1  UNION ALL SELECT 'R_Prosthetics' as TheSchema, 'HomeOxygenRxF665x193' as TheTable, 'PrimaryIcdSID' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount FROM [R_Prosthetics].[HomeOxygenRxF665x193] WHERE [PrimaryIcdSID] = -1
```

I’m not experienced enough to dispute but didn’t make sense to me so would like 2nd opinion.  DBA says I must add NOLOCK to my FROOM  statement "FROM Table AS a WITH (NOLOCK)".  Does he have a valid point?  I've read that a shared lock is issued with every SELECT statement but I don't see any queries in Stored Procedures & Functions and SSIS packages that issue a NOLOCK anywhere in our environment.  If this is a critical issue you would think the DBA would make this a requirement for all queries.  His statement to me suggested that the shared lock remained in effect for the entire procedure which includes hundreds of UNION ALL queries because of the UNION ALL.  That doesn't make sense.  It would make more sense that a Shared Lock would be released when each query completed.

```
--=================================
--Find negative sids and store references in ##GetSID

SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##GetSid') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##GetSid
Create Table ##GetSid (MySchema nvarchar(max), MyTable nvarchar(max), MyColumn nvarchar(max), NegativeSIDCount int)
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) Schemaname
    , t.name AS TableName
    , c.name AS ColName
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
--WHERE right(c.name,3) LIKE '%SID%'
WHERE right(c.name,3) LIKE '%SID%' and Schema_Name(t.Schema_id) like 'R_%' and Schema_Name(t.Schema_id) not in('R_Stage', 'R_MorningReport', 'R_Outside', 'R_CompPen')

OPEN MyCursor

DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(100), @Table VARCHAR(100), @Column VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @Schema, @Table, @Column
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN   
    IF LEN(@sql) > 0 
        SET @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL '

    SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT ''' + @Schema + ''' as TheSchema, ''' + @Table + ''' as TheTable, ''' + @Column + ''' as TheColumn, COUNT(*) as NullCount '
    SET @sql = @sql + 'FROM [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Table + '] WHERE [' + @Column + '] = -1 '


    FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @Schema, @Table, @Column
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor

Insert into ##GetSid
exec sp_executesql @sql
delete from ##GetSid where  NegativeSIDCount = 0
select * from ##GetSid


--================================
--Update negative SIDS to NULL

DECLARE @MySchema VARCHAR(100), @MyTable VARCHAR(100), @MyColumn VARCHAR(100), @MyCount varchar(100)
--DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)='';   -- uncomment to run this section by itself


SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
select MySchema, Mytable, MyColumn, NegativeSIDCount
from ##GetSID
OPEN MyCursor

FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @MySchema, @MyTable, @MyColumn, @MyCount
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

set @SQL = 'Update  ' + @MySchema + '.' + @Mytable + char(10) + 'Set ' + @MyColumn + ' = NULL' + char(10) + 'Where  ' + @MyCount + '  >  0 AND ' + @MyColumn + '  = -1 ' + char(10)
exec sp_executesql @sql
--print @sql    

    FETCH FROM MyCursor INTO @MySchema, @MyTable, @MyColumn, @MyCount
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: I agree that an improvement over putting `WITH (NOLOCK)` against multiple tables is to just put one `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` at the start. But an even better improvement for you be to just move your `Insert into ##GetSid` _into_ your cursor. This means you just trickle lots of little counts into your temp table piecemeal  rather than running one enormous `UNION ALL`. This is no less accurate than using `NOLOCK`. You break your selects up into lots of little chunks.

Comment: Nick, would you mind explaining "rather than running one enormous UNION ALL" please.  Are you saying that this query which has several hundred select statements UNIONed together will place locks on all tables referenced until the entire query completes?

Comment: I don't know whether it locks all tables until all records are returned. Ideally it would do them all in parallel and unlock as they are finished. It might do it differently each time you run it depending on what else is going on. Your DBA should be able to see if this query is causing many locks or not. It should actually indicate which object (page, row, table) is being locked and causing the issue - one table or many? Why don't you also try my suggestion of breaking it up and at least see if it performs the same or worse so you know if it's an option.

Comment: I will try your suggestion but I'm trying to understand how SQL works under the hood.  If it operated in parallel that would be fine provided it release the lock on each table as it finished.

The DBA did a 'drive by', made the comments and went on vacation.

I'll upload the query plan if I can figure out how to do that.  I don't see anything wrong with it myself other than a lot of queries are happening (790).  I don't see where it shows locks.

Comment: For example you could download `sp_WhoIsActive` and schedule it to snapshot every 5 seconds and you might see how locks are made and released over time. Query plan doesn't shows locks but it can give clues on how you can improve perforamance although you wouldn't glean much for a select count(*) over 790 tables. The plan is 'how am I going to do this efficiently'. locks are 'while I am actually running this plan how do I get the resources I need while everything else is accessing the same table'

Comment: I'm not DBA on the system but they have installed it and I use it all the time but it doesn't show locks other than blocking.

Profiler is probably the only tool that does and I don't have access or know how to use it.

Comment: Ha you're right I just assume everything is in there since it's so handy. Instead you could use `sys.dm_tran_locks` or `sp_lock` to work out what your spid has locked at the time, but this is often 'fleeting' unless it's blocking for a while. You could run this repeatedly to work it out.. then you could write a blog explaining what happens!

Comment: Thanks. Haven't tried those.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

IMHO,DBA suggestion are more generalise than specialise.

Ask DBA,what if we put SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
at the top of proc,instead of multiple NOLOCK.

Both are same things.
One thing for sure,do not use nolock in insert/update/delete sql.

One example proc1 is using ,

Select * from table1 (with (nolock)

Another proc2 using same table but no ISOLATION LEVEL is being use
(default is READ CoMMITTED)

insert into table1

then i think proc1 may be valid.it will release any lock.

But if proc2 was using any other type lock then proc1 may be wrong.
depending upon the requirement.

Like is it ok to read uncommitted data.if no then you hv to remove (nolock) from proc1.

BTW,why have you posted that script ?

I welcome criticism on my opinion.

Comment: Added script in case anyone wanted to see the code DBA critiqued.

Comment: Yes, I posted script.  It will run on any system provided the first where clause is modified to your criteria.